# Unable to connect to sftp in Airflow and receiving Name or service not known

Tags: amazon-s3, airflow, sftp

I'm using the  s3_to_sftp_operator in one of my tasks. Connection in AirFlow is set up like below.

Conn Id: sftp_outbound
Conn Type: FTP
Host: ftp2.companyname.com
Schema:
Login: username
Password: password
Port:  tried with blank and 22
Extra: {"no_host_key_check": true}

Stack trace for error below.

```
    ERROR - [Errno -2] Name or service not known
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 984, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/s3_to_sftp_operator.py", line 81, in execute
    sftp_client = ssh_hook.get_conn().open_sftp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/ssh_hook.py", line 194, in get_conn
    client.connect(**connect_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 340, in connect
    to_try = list(self._families_and_addresses(hostname, port))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 204, in _families_and_addresses
    hostname, port, socket.AF_UNSPEC, socket.SOCK_STREAM
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Yes, I can.  I figured out the issue.  When using airflow s3_to_sftp_operator, leave connection type blank when you are setting up the connection.

Comment: If you have a solution, please post it as an answer.

Comment: we can't do that in airflow anymore I think, there has to be a connection_type while setting up the connection, I am facing the same issue. when I do ftp.companyname.com, it says connection reset by peer, when i do sftp://ftp.companyname.com, it gives me this error. can you please help